# Command "xset dpms force on" after resume

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, display, suspend

I Use Lubuntu 13.04 and the LVDS Display only works if you use the "nomodeset" option is set in grub.
(The VGA Display works without a problem...)

After a resume i only can see on the LVDS Display graphic-errors, the VGA Display works.
If i then use the command "xset dpms force on" in the terminal, the LVDS Display works.

How can i do this automatically after Resume?

My script didn't work.
/etc/pm/sleep.d/05lcd

```
    #!/bin/bash
    case "$1" in
thaw|resume) 
    /usr/bin/xset dpms force on   2>/dev/null
    ;;
*)
    ;;
    esac
```

if i type

```
bash /etc/pm/sleep.d/05lcd thaw
```

in the Terminal the script works... =(

Comment: My best guess: Add the lines "export DISPLAY=:0" 
 and "export XAUTHORITY=/var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority" before the line " /usr/bin/xset dpms force on   2>/dev/null"